# Implementing Node.js on an online server

Tags: hosting, node.js

I've been reading about Node.js and doing some tutorials, and so far I'm liking it a lot, however I've been trying to find ways to implement it on an online server and so far I haven't found anything, is there any way to do this? Should it be installed the same way I installed it locally but on the online server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently you need a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) and setup Node like you would do it locally, you should also take a look at [this article](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever) on how to make sure that your Node.js process runs all the time.

There are a couple of easy solutions coming up though:

1. Heroku, has announced a closed beta for Node.js support [last April](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/4/28/node_js_support_experimental/), but since then there haven't been any updates on the topic.
2. Joyent (which recently announced to support Node.js development) also has a [closed beta](https://no.de/) at the moment, but it's full.
3. Last but not least, there's [Nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com/), also in private beta at the moment, I don't have any further information on their status though.

As for when those three go public, no idea, but I guess Joyent will be the first to offer their service.
So, right now you'll have to go with the VPS solution and a hoster of your choice.